# How to make a scaling project using CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, scalability

I wanto to know if there is some tutorials, books etc.
that explai how to make a scaling project using CakePHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good article on how to speed up cakephp performance. Also take a look at the comments after the article.

http://www.pseudocoder.com/archives/2009/03/17/8-ways-to-speed-up-cakephp-apps/

Answer (score 1):

I would look first at optimisation over scalability. CakePHP is very able to handle large applications and databases. But in answer to your question...

1. Try Googling "Cakephp scalability"
2. http://philip.greenspun.com/seia/scaling
3. http://www.rawseo.com/news/2009/06/25/better-ways-to-improve-php-application-performance/

Comment: I have not found many resources trying Googling "Cakephp scalability"

Comment: Interesting, I found 448,000. Are you connected to the internet? http://bit.ly/googlecakephpscalability

Comment: I'm connected. in many of those resources is not explained anything on how to scale cakephp. However, thank you.